# How do I create a custom Sqlite UDF while using ipython-sql in a Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

How would I go about creating a custom SQLite UDF in Jupyter/iPython with ipython-sql (https://github.com/catherinedevlin/ipython-sql)
or another iPython SQL magic library?

I'm trying to do something like this...

```
%load_ext sql
%sql sqlite:///

%sql create table example(col text)
%sql insert into example (col) values ('stuff')

to_upper = lambda x: x.upper()

%sql select upper(col) from example
```

When using the sqlite3 Python library it would be...

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

conn = create_engine('sqlite://')
conn.execute('create table example(col text)')
conn.execute("insert into example values ('stuff')")

to_upper = lambda x: x.upper()

connection = conn.raw_connection()
connection.create_function('to_upper', 1, to_upper)
print(conn.execute("select to_upper(col) col from example").fetchall()[0][0])
```

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

```
%load_ext sql
%sql sqlite:///

%sql create table example(col text)
%sql insert into example (col) values ('stuff')

to_upper = lambda x: x.upper()

x=%sql -l
connection=x['sqlite://'].session.connection.connection

connection.create_function('to_upper', 1, to_upper)

%sql select upper(col) from example
```